# How do I exit a for loop with a key press?

Tags: c#, do-while

For my ASSIGNMENT, I am running this loop to gather id #'s and names in a 2d array. 
But I would like to be able to break out of the loop if the user doesn't want to sit and enter 30 sets of numbers and names. Because... why would they?!

```
string[,] studentNames = new string[30,30];

// Accepting value from user 
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    Console.Write("\nEnter id #, Student Name :\t");

    //Storing value in an array
    studentNames[i, 0] = (Console.ReadLine());
}
```

I've tried adding:

```
do
{
 //the stuff
} while(Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: my hint, "if" and "break"

Comment: "break" is used to break out from any loop. This wil help a lot: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_loops.htm

Comment: also, assigning the `Console.ReadLine()` result to a variable will probably help.

Comment: My instructor doesn't like us using "break" unless it's in a switch

Comment: @JeremyThompson- not using VBA.

Comment: If you can't use `break`, you will have to change your loop to something other than a `for` loop.

Comment: If duplicate is not enough make sure to search for similar questions (i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+exit+for+loop+on+key) and than [edit] your post to clarify why it is not a duplicate or ask new question.

Comment: For learning's sake, [here](https://pastebin.com/vPLmWdLC) is the source code for a version with a re-implemented input method that allows you to press the escape key at any time to exit.  I urge you not to turn this in as your homework answer because they will *know* right away that you didn't write it yourself (unless they taught you about lambdas and anonymous methods already).  It is quick and dirty; it could probably be done much better than this, but it was all I had time for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
readLine = (Console.ReadLine());
if(readLine == "exit") break;
studentNames[i, 0] = readLine;
```

That will exit if user input the word exit. Depending on the language, the comparation `readLine == "exit"` may have to be replaced by some string comparing funcition.

I hope it helps.

Comment: So is the keypress of 'esc' not an option in this scenario?

Comment: @MichaelM Not easily if you are using `Console.ReadLine` to input text.  It "blocks" until it sees you press "enter". "esc" won't trigger it.  You would have to change your entire input mechanism to input one character at a time, building the "real" string as you go, and watching for the "esc" key.  It's possible, but probably beyond those scope of your homework assignment.